# Finding and attacking an IMAP Server

Tags: password-cracking, hydra, imap

For a security challenge I am supposed to dictionary attack an IMAP service. A rather simple exercise using hydra.

So far I failed, since I've given hydra the actual website instead of the mail server. How can I find a sites mail server? Something like `imap.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

I am not sure about the username either. Does the account that hydra expects have to have an `@example.com` ending?

EDIT 1:

I tested bashCypher's clue with the dig command. This appeared:
[image]

is this postmaster.xxx.com what I'm looking for?

So far I tried to attack the main website which was handed out to me. Hydra with a dictionary and a username didn't show any errors. It worked for hours and never found a pwd. Despite the fact that the pwd should be rather easy...

Comment: You didn't pull an answer. The authority section says where it got its information from. Try it again and ask a different name server. So try "dig [domain] @8.8.8.8 MX " This only works if it's externally exposed and not in a school lab or etc. Also have you run a port scan against it? If port 143 is open you can just attack that port without knowing the DNS mail name.

Comment: @bashCypher tried that aswell still nothing... about name server. the whole thing is in a VPN. doest that make sense to call a name server? 8.8.8.8 is a google name server isn't it? Google can't know that url.

Comment: That's a bit confusing. So anything behind that VPN still needs dns to use domains and urls. I'm assuming you mean "VPN in" which makes me think this is a closed environment and the url's are handled by a local DNS server, not an external one. 8.8.8.8 is google DNS, and if it's an external website it should be there or forwarded to a zone that would know it. My instinct is you're not at the right server. Can you see any emails on the webpage? Like a contacts section? If the domain is different try digging that. [name]@[domain] so Bash@gmail.com, gmail.com is domain.

Comment: @bashCypher yes thats it sorry. It's a closed environment with some webpages. I can connect with my credentials in a special Kali Distribution to their VPN. 
Yes indeed there is. It's some kind of shopping page. The email in the contact section is completely different, but still something made up inside the VPN (no gmail or aol).

Comment: @bashCypher got an answer... I hope this is what I need. Despite the fact that this domain is completely different to the website domain.

Comment: You should remove the server names from your question.

Comment: @TomK. I removed the VPN server name. The ones below only exist in the honeypot. Nobody should find them. But I can remove them if you think its a risk

Comment: Nothing is gained from the names being "correct", so better be safe than sorry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check mail server DNS listings for a domain with dig (linux). Glad to hear it's an approved honey pot. Good luck.

```
dig [domain] MX
```

example:

```
dig google.com MX

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.5 <<>> google.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27957
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             600     IN      MX      50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             600     IN      MX      10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             600     IN      MX      20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             600     IN      MX      30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             600     IN      MX      40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
```

.

You can also use NSlookup, with more steps. See here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998082(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: thank you for this suggestion! i posted the response in my question. could you might give me a hint if this is what i'm looking for?

Comment: `MX` is simply the wrong answer. MX stands for mail exchange and refers to the MTA (that's typically the SMTP server). To find the IMAP service related to a particular zone (domain) one should be using `TXT` and/or `SRV` records.

Comment: @0xC0000022L check this article for more information https://www.wireload.net/news/2011/12/understanding_email_routing_ie_mx-records.html IMAP is a client, so if you want to see the mail server MX is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Be careful of attacking random targets on the Internet unless you have an order to do any "white hat" / ethical hacking by the owner of the information systems you are trying to break into. Otherwise you may become liable to civil and crime investigations.

Having said that, the initial intuition would be that there is no way to tell a domain's IMAP server in a similar way as you could just lookup a domain's MX (SMTP) server through the DNS system.

But there is; at least for some domains. Some domains use autoconfiguration mechanisms to make it easy for people using their services to configure their MUAs. Take a look at

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Autoconfiguration
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010-technical-article/jj591328(v=exchg.141)

for technical details. YMMV.

The answer to the 2nd part of your question is almost the same:

Some systems use the user's email address as a username, some don't. But if the domain in question is configured to use either Autodiscovery or Autoconfig, the service will also tell you the username that belongs to an email address.

Please not not disregard my warning in the beginning! You may harm yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot. everything fine, it's a honeypot for a competition :)

Comment: Shame it's buried in a link, but the true gist is to look out for `TXT` and `SRV` records, not `MX`. `MX` refers to the [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) address and may _happen_ to point to the host running the IMAP server.